# Jade4J not recognizing JSON objects

Tags: grails, pug

If I do the following

```
h1= firstName
```

I get

```
<h1>{"test":"test"}
              </h1>
```

But If I do

```
h1= firstName.test
```

Nothing shows up

*Using grails-jade plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Jade4J does not support JSON only Java